# Why do I get a big error when I compute this integral with Gauss-Legendre Quadrature?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation, matlab

I'm using Gauss-Legendre Quadrature to solve the following integral:

> $\int_0^{1}x^xdx$

After I've compared the result with the MatLab vpa(int(...)) of the same integral I've noticed that the error between the quadrature approximation and MatLab's result is quite significant.

Why is that ? Is it possible that I've made a mistake somewhere, or it's a bad behaved integral when it comes to approximation ?

**UPDATE**
I've made a mistake, it was actually $x^x$ not $x^2$
Here is the matlab code

```
syms x;
f = x^x;
r = int(x^x, x, 0, 1)
vpaRes = vpa(r, 10)
% change of interval
f = @(t)((1./2).*(((t+1)./2) .^((t+1)./2)));
[nodes, coefficients] = GaussLegendre(10);
I = vquad(nodes, coefficients, f);
gaussRes = vpa(I);
error = vpaRes - gaussRes;
```

GaussLegendre - function that computes the nodes and coefficients of a Gauss-Legendre polynomial 
vquad - function that computes the approximation using nodes and coefficients and the function

Both functions are tested and are behaving as expected in other cases.

Am I not using enough nodes ? Or I've made a mistake somewhere, as you can see I've made the change of interval.

Comment: Yes, it is possible that you made a mistake somewhere, but without showing any code or anything, it's impossible to know.

Comment: It's a very well-behaved integral.  It's quite likely you've made a mistake, or maybe you're just using a very small $n$.

Comment: I do not know exactly what you are using, but if it is the usual one, that is exact for quadratics.

Comment: Have you accidentally forgotten to change nodes and weights for $[-1, 1]$ interval?

Comment: I've added the code and some explanations, thank you all for replying

Comment: Are `GaussLegendre` and `vquad` your own functions or are they something available online. You should supply links tho them in either case.

Comment: The error for Gaussian quadrature is estimated using some derivative of your integrand.  If that derivative is unbounded (as in this case), then the error estimate tells you nothing!